# Why is a 103Z capacitor use with N20 DC motor?

Tags: capacitor, dc-motor

So capacitor 103z is used in parallel with N20 DC motor, I would like to know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reduces EMI produced by the motor by absorbing high frequency noise.